# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I tried to make a custom keyboard using [this tutorial on tuts+](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615), but when I run it and change the keyboard I get the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.ginso.simplekeyboard.SimpleIME: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ginso.simplekeyboard.SimpleIME" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ginso.simplekeyboard-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I tried to remove the dot in the manifest in 
`<service android:name=".SimpleIME" />`.
I also tried the code for manifest someone posted in the comments. But nothing changed. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
`SimpleIME` is located in the standard package.

Comment: Posting your source code may help, especially your main class and its package.

Comment: the code is the same as in the link, exept that my package is named com.ginso.simplekeyboard

Comment: Have you changed the package of your `SimpleIME` class as well?

Comment: it's in the standard package

Comment: I doubt anyone will download your files like this. You should include the relevant portions of the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you put `SimpleIME` in the standard package, Android isn't able to load `com.ginso.simplekeyboard.SimpleIME`, which you declared as your service.

The [*<service>* documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#nm) states for `android:name`

> This should be a fully qualified class name (such as, "com.example.project.RoomService"). However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period (for example, ".RoomService"), it is appended to the package name specified in the *<manifest>* element.

As far as I know, there's no way to use to use a class in the standard package, so just put `SimpleIME` in the `com.ginso.simplekeyboard` package and everything should work.